# Mongodb indexed count complexity linear in number of results

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb collection with an index on 'a'.
When executing a count query to find all elements with 'a':5, the number of keys examined by mongodb increases linearly with the result. Since the index is a b-tree structure, I suspect this is not actually necessary.

Here is how the index look like:

```
db.coll.getIndexes()
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "a" : 1
    },
    "name" : "a_1",
    "ns" : "db.coll"
},
...
]
```

And the (truncated) result of the explained count:

```
db.coll.explain('executionStats').count({'a':5})
"stage" : "COUNT_SCAN",
            "nReturned" : 9179,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 9180,
            "advanced" : 9179
```

Comment: The count has to go through a section of the B-tree that increases linearly with the number of hits. So it will be very fast for a small number of hits in a large collection, but not super-fast for a very large number of hits.